# Javascript - how expensive is it to access variables in a function's outer scope?

Tags: javascript, performance, scope

I'm not too familiar with JavaScript's mechanics of scope resolution.
I was wondering, how expensive is it for JavaScript to access variables that are one or two scopes "upwards" in the scope chain? 
Say I have a function named scope3 that is inside a function named scope2 which is inside a function named scope1.
If I try to access a variable defined in scope1 from scope3, does JavaScript have to load all variables in all three scopes in order to find it? If so, the expensiveness of such operation depends on how many variables are defined in each scope, correct?

The doubt arose because I have multiple functions that make use of the same elements or values. Values that require a function call to be calculated. 
So, I was wondering if it is more efficient to retrieve the elements and re-calculate the values in each function, to avoid climbing the scope chain, or if it is best to wrap the functions inside an outer scope, retrieve the elements / calculate the values only once, and then simply access them from the inner functions.
This, of course, is a semplified example of my structure. In reality I have multiple scoping levels.

What is best-practice for cases like this?

Thank you.

Comment: That can depend on the engine, what optimizations it applies, etc. To get a definite answer, try both approaches and profile your code (in different browsers). Then choose the better one.

Answer (score 0):

I create a small [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/cost-of-closures2) test to have an idea.

- v8 (chromium) is super fast when there is no closure, but a lot slower with closure. How 'far' it has to reach to get the variable is not relevant.
- Spidermonkey (firefox) is slower (50% of chrome max speed) but the speed is consistent.

So as a first approximation, you can consider closures to be slower. The number of nesting level has no impact on speed though.

Answer (score -1):

You could pass the variable as parameter (if possible in your code), it's not expensive and it's cleaner.